# How to get all the paginated records in a jqgrid table?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, pagination

I am trying to fetch all the rows of a paginated records(records present in all the pages). However, I am getting only the records in the first page. How can I get all the records in the table? Is there a way to achieve this only using javascript?
I am using jquery filters in order to get filtered records in jqgrid, so I need to get the filtered data spread across multiple pages.

```
var x=$("#list").getGridParam("reccount");//get only current page records count.

var gridData = $("#list").jqGrid('getRowData');// get only current page records

$("#list").jqGrid('getGridParam','data');//obtain all records but not filtered records in all     pages
```

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var grid = $("#list"),
mydata = [
  {id:"1",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
  {id:"2",invdate:"2007-10-    02",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
  {id:"3",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"},
  {id:"4",invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
  {id:"5",invdate:"2007-10-05",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
  {id:"6",invdate:"2007-09-06",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"},
  {id:"7",invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
  {id:"8",invdate:"2007-10-03",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
  {id:"9",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"},
  {id:"10",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
  {id:"11",invdate:"2007-10-02",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
  {id:"12",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"},
  {id:"13",invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
  {id:"14",invdate:"2007-10-05",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
  {id:"15",invdate:"2007-09-06",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"},
  {id:"16",invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
  {id:"17",invdate:"2007-10-03",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
  {id:"18",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"}
];
grid.jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    data: mydata,
    colNames:['Inv No','Date', 'Client', 'Amount','Tax','Total','Notes'],
    colModel:[
      {name:'id',index:'id', key: true, width:70, sorttype:"int"},
      {name:'invdate',index:'invdate', width:90, sorttype:"date"},
      {name:'name',index:'name', width:100},
      {name:'amount',index:'amount', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float"},
      {name:'tax',index:'tax', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float"},
      {name:'total',index:'total', width:80,align:"right",sorttype:"float"},
      {name:'note',index:'note', width:150, sortable:false}
   ],
   search:true,
   pager:'#pager',
   jsonReader: {cell:""},
   rowNum: 8,
   rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
   sortname: 'id',
   sortorder: 'asc',
   viewrecords: true,
   height: "100%",
   caption: "Multiple search with local data"
 });
grid.jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{add:false,edit:false,del:false,search:true,refresh:true},
{},{},{},{multipleSearch:true, multipleGroup:true, showQuery: true});

});
```

Comment: Please post code for how you apply filter on jqgrid..

Comment: Hi yagnesh.. please check out below link for applying filters..
http://jsbin.com/xeyeroha/5/edit  ......  in the example, select 'test' option from select picker and click on apply filter.. it will result in giving 2 pages of records.....  Kindly suggest how to fetch all the rows in both the pages... Thanks...,

Comment: See my answer below. may that will help you.

Comment: include `loadComplete` when you initialize jqgrid. If you already use it than include this `this.p.lastSelected = lastSelected;` inside it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `loadComplete(){}` callback of jQgrid:

```
loadComplete: function(gridData){
   console.log(gridData); // will print all the records available in the grid.
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jai. You pointed me in right direction. I answered this question above.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you need all rows data of grid without pagination

There is no any function available to get filter data directly.Internally `JqGrid` uses [$.jgrid.from](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.3.1/js/grid.base.js#L176-612) to filter local data.
To get all rows data of JqGrid after apply filter used below function :

```
var oldFrom = $.jgrid.from,lastSelected;

$.jgrid.from = function (source, initalQuery) 
{
    var result = oldFrom.call(this, source, initalQuery),
    old_select = result.select;
    result.select = function (f) {
        lastSelected = old_select.call(this, f);
        return lastSelected;
    };
    return result;
};
```

`lastSelected` will return the array of all rows data after apply filter on grid elements which are results of the last sorting or filtering operation.
`$.jgrid.from` is global the data are not connected to the grid. If you have more as one grid on the page it will be uncomfortable. One can fix the small disadvantage with the following line in the code of `loadComplate` of every grid:

```
loadComplete: function () {
    this.p.lastSelected = lastSelected;
}
```

By above code we add new JqGrid parameter `lastSelected` which will have similar as data parameter, but will hold only last filtered data.

You can get filter data by below code :

```
var filteredData = $grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'lastSelected');
```

[**JqGrid Demo (Get all data after filter)**](http://jsbin.com/xeyeroha/7/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Hi Yagnesh.. Thanks for the answer .. much appreciated.. But can you suggest how to include your code in "loadcomplete" because I am already using "loadcomplete" once in my code...

Comment: merger my code into your code.. add my line present in `loadcomplete` to your function.

Comment: Thanks yagnesh.. i am getting all the filtered records but the only problem is on clicking 2nd time on applyfilters(), it returns data objects... but on first click it returns 'null'... also , a picture with tag "loading..." will appear. can you suggest how to overcome this issue?

Comment: Update your code in `jsbin` and provide updated link. I doesn't seen any problem in my code.